# How to change a the colors of specific rows and columns in a table?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, colors

I've been working on a project where I intend to use tkinter to create a window with a table containing all my results. To do this, I have the following code. The code runs just fine, but the problem is I need to attribute some colors to specific rows and columns while with the current code it all ends up in blue. Let's say for example I need to have the first 3 rows of column 1 in red. Any ideas about howthis can be done? Thank you very much for any help.

```
# Create a table for tkinter

class Table:

def __init__(self, root):

    # code for creating table
    for i in range(total_rows):
        for j in range(total_columns):
            self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='blue',
                           font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
            self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
            self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])


# take the data
lst = [(1, 'Raj', 'Mumbai', 19),
       (2, 'Aaryan', 'Pune', 18),
       (3, 'Vaishnavi', 'Mumbai', 20),
       (4, 'Rachna', 'Mumbai', 21),
       (5, 'Shubham', 'Delhi', 21)]

# find total number of rows and columns in list for tkinter
total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])


# create root window
root = Tk()
root.title("Results")
t = Table(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should put all of the `<tkinter.Entry>` objects in a list. Then you can iterate over them using a `for` loop and use `entry.config(bg=<new background colour>)` or `entry.config(fg=<new foreground colour>)`

Comment: How to put all Entry objects in a list? Could you please give an example with the list you're talking about ?

Comment: Btw yesterday I made my own table widget using tkinter so your timing is perfect :D.

Comment: Glad to hear that :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


# It's better to inherit from `tkinter.Frame` so we can use the table
# as a normal tkinter widget
class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, data=[], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.table = []
        for i, _list in enumerate(data):
            row = []
            for j, entry_data in enumerate(_list):
                entry = tk.Entry(self, width=20, fg="blue",
                                 font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
                entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
                entry.insert("end", entry_data)
                row.append(entry)
            self.table.append(row)

    def column_config(self, column_number, **kwargs):
        for row in self.table:
            # Call `<tkinter.Entry>.config(**kwargs)`
            row[column_number].config(**kwargs)
              


# take the data
data = [(1, "Raj", "Mumbai", 19),
        (2, "Aaryan", "Pune", 18),
        (3, "Vaishnavi", "Mumbai", 20),
        (4, "Rachna", "Mumbai", 21),
        (5, "Shubham", "Delhi", 21)]

# create root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Results")
table = Table(root, data)
table.pack()
# Column 3 is the last one
table.column_config(3, fg="red", bg="cyan")
root.mainloop()
```

I made a few changes:

- I put made the `Table` act as any other `tkinter` widget by inheriting from `tkinter.Frame`
- I also put all of the entries in a list so I can access them later
- Also I added the `column_config` method

Comment: It seems better indeed. I'll try to modify my main code according to this. Thank you very much!